# SQL: change primary key from integer to float

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, integer, primary-key

I am working for an NGO and we have a members table which is sorted with an integer primary key. We would like to create sub members, i.e., a member could be a company, and sub members could be employees of this company.

One idea I had would be to change the primary key from integer to float to allow keys like 1.001, 1.002 etc.

Does that make sense or is there any better way to accomplish this task?

What's the easiest way to change the primary key type?

Comment: Don't do it. Use another column to sort. Primary key columns' only goal is to ensure row uniqueness. Their value should be of no importance to you as long as the ensure row uniqueness. I would strongly suggest you use synthetic pks instead of natural keys.

Comment: never use float.  possibly use decimal.  but agreed with The Impaler that primary keys should be treated as arbitrary values; if you want sorting, use a different column.

Comment: There are no "keys like 1.001, 1.002". Those literals do not represent floats with those values. Read about basics of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by company then by member, then use multiple columns in the ORDER BY:

```
SELECT
...
ORDER BY company, id;
```

It's a bad idea to use FLOAT for a column that needs to be unique, because FLOAT is an inexact numeric. Values may round in ways you don't expect.

See also:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

In addition to the risk of duplicates, I agree with the comments above that the primary key should not be overloaded with information about what company the member belongs to. Use an attribute column for that. If nothing else, think about what if a member changes their company? Or if members can belong to more than one company concurrently?